# Class vs Prototype

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

What makes ES6 class syntax better than traditional prototype approach?

Should I replace all my current objects with classes since I don't care about the cross browser stuff?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just syntactical sugar - it's still prototype based under the hood.

Comment: There's a difference between _"not caring"_ for browser compatibility, and actively breaking your code.

Comment: Should note that if you want to start writing ES6 while still producing production-usable javascript cross-browser you should take a look at [Google's Traceur transpiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

Comment: Yeah, it's very important to understand that the fundamental principles of JS don't really change. The `class` syntax is just syntactic sugar, just like e.g. arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 classes are a simple sugar over the prototype-based OO pattern. Having a single convenient declarative form makes class patterns easier to use, and encourages interoperability. Classes support prototype-based inheritance, super calls, instance and static methods and constructors.

Comment: In addition it also also a little less error prone but not allowing classes to be called without `new`.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 class based syntax is much better than traditional prototype approach,

- Compared to constructors and constructor inheritance, classes make
     it easier for beginners to get started.
- Subclassing is supported within the language.
- Built-in constructors are subclassable.
- No library for inheritance is needed, anymore; code will become more
     portable between frameworks.
- They provide a foundation for advanced features in the future
     (mixins and more).

So if you don't care about cross browser, then go with class based syntax.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

For the most part classes are just syntactic sugar over the old way. We'll get back to that in a minute, but there is at least one thing classes can do that the old way *can't*: properly extend built-in constructors like Array and HTMLElement. Additionally, classes will automatically throw when not called with `new` whereas the old way was to add an `instanceof` check in the constructor.

Now for the sugar, consider this old-style constructor function:

```
function Foo(bar) {
  this._bar = bar;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
    get: function() { return this._bar },
    set: function(value) {
      console.log(value);
      this._bar = value;
    }
  });
};

Foo.prototype.someMethod = function() { return this.bar + 5 };
Foo.someStaticMethod = function() { return 3 };
```

That's kinda... ugly. Consider the equivalent class:

```
class Foo {
  static someStaticMethod () {
    return 3;
  }

  constructor (bar) {
    this._bar = bar;
  }

  get bar () {
    return this._bar;
  }

  set bar (value) {
    console.log(value);
  }

  someMethod () {
    return this.bar + 5;
  }
}
```

Much cleaner. Whether or not you should re-write existing code is more of a toss-up, but definitely use classes for the new stuff.